# Separate info.plist for different iOS versions?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, statusbar

Could anyone help me with having different info.plist's for different versions of iOS? (In this case 6 and 7)? Specifically, I'm trying to make the status bar show for iOS 7 and hidden for iOS 6. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

This will return the os version.  I wouldn't store the os in a plist when you can return it with a method call fairly easily.

Comment: How does this allow you to specify two different Info.plist files? (Hint - it doesn't).

Comment: Doesn't seem like a valid use case for two different plists.

Comment: The asker's question is either based on a faulty premise or is leaving out information that would necessitate multiple application bundle property lists. As is, this answer is vastly better than trying to get an app bundle to do something it can't (especially considering checking the version and setting `UIApplication#statusBarHidden` accordingly is saner than trying to conditionally hide the status bar via the app's property list).

Comment: I like how you provided a solution, instead of a specific answer.

Comment: This is not a good answer. It doesn't answer the question. The question is valid. He wants to show the status bar initially on iOS 7, but hide it initially on iOS 6. No code can do that, because it's Springboard doing this before the app has any run time. Whether or not that's Info.plist per iOS version or something else, that's the question.